# Find the number of all typed commands which include a string , using grep

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I'm searching through my bash history log for all the typed (started) commands which included the string `x`. For some reason, the homework checker always says that the number I'm giving is bigger than the actual one.

Here is what I've typed :

```
grep -o 'x' "/home/user/.bash_history" | wc -l >> FILE
```

Comment: Why are you using `-o` in `grep`?

Comment: grep's `-c` option might come in useful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what homework checker you are referring to but the issue here is probably that you are not counting lines with `x`, youi are counting occurences of `x`. The `-o` flag makes `grep` print only the matched portion of a line, if there are many `x`s on the same line, it will print each of them separately:

```
$ echo "xxx" | grep -o x
x
x
x
```

So, you don't want `-o` there. You also don't need `wc`, that's what grep's `-c` option is for:

```
$ history | grep -c x
1001
```

In the future, make sure to read a command's man page before using its options. That will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You need a better search, the **grep** command can search using regular expressions.

**From man grep**:

```
DESCRIPTION
grep  searches  the  named  input  FILEs for lines containing a 
match to the given PATTERN.
```

And as "Ulrich Schwarz" said, you can use the -c parameter to count.

**From man grep**:

```
-c, --count
Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for
each input file.
```

So, searching through the bash_history for a command execution using regular expressions and then counting them:

```
grep -E "EXP" .bash_history
```

or just

```
grep "EXP" .bash_history
```

**Example**: If you want to count the amount of 'rm' commands:

```
grep -E ^rm* /home/<user>/.bash_history -c
```

or just

```
grep ^rm* /home/<user>/.bash_history -c
```

**Example 2**: If you want to count the amount of commands that has the string **X**:

```
grep -E X /home/<user>/.bash_history -c
```

or just

```
grep X /home/<user>/.bash_history -c
```

**For more info about regular expressions**: [GNU - grep-regular-expression-syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html)

Comment: Note that even without `-E`, grep matches regular expressions; just not the exact same type of regular expressions.